# Analyse Typescript with SonarQube

Tags: typescript, sonarqube, sonarlint, tslint

I'm using `node_modules/codelyzer` to analyze my source code `Typescript`. I define manually rules in `tslint.json` file.

But it is possible to analyze `Typescript` with `SonarQube`?

Comment: As of Aug 22, 2017 it looks like the SonarQube team released [SonarTS v1.0](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/SonarTS). Note: this is different than [Pablissimo's SonarTsPlugin](https://github.com/Pablissimo/SonarTsPlugin).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use a plugin developed by the SonarQube community to support TypeScript.

You will find it on the "Other Plugins" page on the official [SonarQube Plugin Library](https://redirect.sonarsource.com/doc/plugin-library.html).

Answer (score 4):

Just to chime in as I did not see the TypeScript plugin on that page. This one seems to be useful: https://github.com/Pablissimo/SonarTsPlugin

Comment: Note that the [SonarQube Plugin Library](https://redirect.sonarsource.com/doc/plugin-library.html) ref'd in @fabrice-sonarsource-team post points to Pablissimo's [source on GitHub](https://github.com/Pablissimo/SonarTsPlugin).

Answer (score 0):

Just in case you are building using Visual Studio 2017, you can use the *SonarScanner for MSBuild 4.2* to build the .NET Core project(s) that contain your Typescript source code.

For example in this case, the following commands are in a *package.json* file for an Angular project:

[image: package.json file for an Angular project]

Set the following commands to be executed during *build* in the *.csproj* file:

[image]

You can then use the .NET Core `dotnet build/publish` tasks to build the project.

After that, end the SonarScanner and analyse the results on SonarQube.
You may see Typescript, Javascript and a bunch of other languages that you may have in your project. Using the VSTS CI tasks makes this uber easy.